# Code to increase and decrease the font does not work

Tags: javascript, fonts, styles, size

I want to increase 3 times, Every time in 2PX.
But it does not give me my fonts to their original size (After the third time it should reset).

```
var textUp = 1;
if (textUp < 4) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allATags.length; i++) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(allATags[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
        var elfontSize = parseInt(style);
        allATags[i].style.fontSize = (elfontSize + 2) + 'px';
    }
    textUp++;
}
else
{
    for (var i = 0; i < allATags.length; i++) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(allATags[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
        var elfontSize = parseInt(style);
        allATags[i].style.fontSize = (elfontSize - 6) + 'px';
    }
    textUp = 1
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it; Check the value of elfontSize in the else clause

Comment: Open the developer tools on the browser of your preference and navigate to the source code. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging